# GTK4 app fonts very large in other window managers

Tags: fonts, gtk4

When I open gtk4 gnome apps (ex. calculator) in other wm's (ex. openbox) the interface font is very large.

[image: link]

Any way to make it smaller? I'm on Ubuntu 22.10.
Thanks.

Comment: +1. And also Gtk4 applications are looking ugly (windows and controls take more space).